# gvisMotionChart : page is not available

Tags: r, vpn, googlevis

I am using VPN to access Google and Google developers(https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart), which runs smoothly for me.

Here is my code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(googleVis))
M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, "Fruit", "Year",
                     options=list(width=600, height=400))
print(M,"chart")
plot(M)
```

It works fine till     `print(M,"chart")` . And I could not access the web of http://127.0.0.1:29441/custom/googleVis/MotionChartID6fd030c744cd.html after `plot(M)`

It shows that the web page is not available.

Updates: I try `plot(M)` without open the VPN, it stops in the page

```
Data: Fruits • Chart ID: MotionChartID6fd036f23b2a • googleVis-0.6.1
  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) • Google Terms of Use • Documentation and Data Policy
```

not redirecting to the page with motion chart I want.

What is the reason of that problem and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an exception to your Chrome content settings, follow these steps:

On your computer, open Chrome.

At the top right, click More More and then Settings.

At the bottom, click Show advanced settings.

Under "Privacy," click Content settings.

Under FLASH, click Manage exceptions.

Allow: 127.0.0.1

The answer was posted by `George Bertini` on `coursera` and the method worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution too, and this worked great.